# cannot import librosa on Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, librosa

I need to analyse the audio spectrum to detect crying, so librosa is needed. I install all the dependencies librosa(0.9.2) need: LLVM11, llvmlite 0.39.1, numba 0.56.2, numpy 1.22.4. However, when I import librosa, the issue comes out. When I import numba, there is no issue coming out. What should I do to fix this problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/librosa/__init__.py", line 209, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/librosa/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .audio import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 12, in <module>
    import resampy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/resampy/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .core import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/resampy/core.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .interpn import resample_f_s, resample_f_p
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/resampy/interpn.py", line 113, in <module>
    def resample_f_p(x, t_out, interp_win, interp_delta, num_table, scale, y):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/np/ufunc/decorators.py", line 194, in wrap
    guvec.add(fty)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/np/ufunc/gufunc.py", line 63, in add
    self.gufunc_builder.add(fty)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/np/ufunc/ufuncbuilder.py", line 241, in add
    cres, args, return_type = _compile_element_wise_function(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/np/ufunc/ufuncbuilder.py", line 173, in _compile_element_wise_function
    cres = nb_func.compile(sig, **targetoptions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/np/ufunc/ufuncbuilder.py", line 121, in compile
    return self._compile_core(sig, flags, locals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/np/ufunc/ufuncbuilder.py", line 154, in _compile_core
    cres = compiler.compile_extra(typingctx, targetctx,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 716, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 452, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 520, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 499, in _compile_core
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 486, in _compile_core
    pm.run(self.state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 368, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 356, in run
    self._runPass(idx, pass_inst, state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 35, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 311, in _runPass
    mutated |= check(pss.run_pass, internal_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 273, in check
    mangled = func(compiler_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py", line 105, in run_pass
    typemap, return_type, calltypes, errs = type_inference_stage(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py", line 83, in type_inference_stage
    errs = infer.propagate(raise_errors=raise_errors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py", line 1086, in propagate
    raise errors[0]
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Internal error at <numba.core.typeinfer.CallConstraint object at 0xab750898>.
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: native lowering)
The 'parallel' target is not currently supported on 32 bit hardware.
During: lowering "id=1[LoopNest(index_variable = parfor_index.44, range = (0, n_out, 1))]{168: <ir.Block at /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/resampy/interpn.py (52)>, 170: <ir.Block at /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/resampy/interpn.py (52)>, 238: <ir.Block at /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/resampy/interpn.py (61)>, 304: <ir.Block at /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/resampy/interpn.py (72)>, 306: <ir.Block at /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/resampy/interpn.py (72)>, 84: <ir.Block at /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/resampy/interpn.py (34)>, 380: <ir.Block at /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/resampy/interpn.py (77)>}Var(parfor_index.44, interpn.py:34)" at /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/resampy/interpn.py (34)
During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function _resample_loop at 0xabd21808>))
During: typing of call at /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/resampy/interpn.py (114)

Enable logging at debug level for details.

File "../../usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/resampy/interpn.py", line 114:
def resample_f_p(x, t_out, interp_win, interp_delta, num_table, scale, y):
    _resample_loop_p(x, t_out, interp_win, interp_delta, num_table, scale, y)
```

Comment: What is unclear to you?

Comment: I dont know what I should do to fix the error that I cannot import librosa library

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst all Raspberry Pi 4 boards are 64-bit they will report themselves as 32-bit when using the normal Raspberry Pi OS as it is 32-bit.

Hence the error.

> The 'parallel' target is not currently supported on 32 bit hardware.

So you will need to use the 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS. You can read about it here: https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-os-64-bit/

And you can download the latest version here:
https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/